# Variable Input appearance and placement. I want each input variable to be placed in their own <td> column rather then the same one

Tags: javascript, html, css

****IMAGE****
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttWGF.png): [https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCTFE.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttWGF.png)

how do I get Input variables to display in different  html TD boxes?
I have 3 TD side by side, I want input 1 to be under TD1, Input 2 to be under TD2 and Input 3 to be under TD3.
However I am getting all inputs under TD1 and not the the rest.

**HTML**

```
    <input type="text" id="inputTask" placeholder="Enter your your task">
    <button onclick="addTask()">Add</button>

<main>
    <table>
        <tr>
            
            <td class="table-data">Task description 1</td>
            <td class="table-data">Task description 2</td>
            <td class="table-data">Task description 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
           <td id="taskName"></td>
           <td id="taskName"></td>
           <td id="taskName"></td>
        </tr>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function addTask() {
let inputTask = document.getElementById('inputTask');
console.log(inputTask.value); 

let ul = document.getElementById('taskName');
ul.innerHTML+= `<p class="table-data">${inputTask.value}</p>`; 
inputTask.value = '';
```

}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i guess this might work for you.

```js
function addTask() {
    let inputTd = document.getElementById('tdInput');
    let inputTask = document.getElementById('inputTask');
      
    let tdOne = document.getElementById('taskName1');
    let tdTwo = document.getElementById('taskName2');
    let tdThree = document.getElementById('taskName3');
    if(inputTask.value != ""){
        if(inputTd.value == 1){
            tdOne.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<p>'+inputTask.value+'</p>');
        }else if(inputTd.value == 2){
            tdTwo.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<p>'+inputTask.value+'</p>');
        }else{
            tdThree.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<p>'+inputTask.value+'</p>');
        } 
    }else{
      alert("Please insert your task!");
    }
  inputTask.value = "";
};
```

```html
<label>Choose TD :</label>
<select id="tdInput">
  <option value="1">TD1</option>
  <option value="2">TD2</option>
  <option value="3">TD3</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="inputTask" placeholder="Enter your your task">
<button id="addTask" type="button" onClick="addTask()">Add</button>
<br><br>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td class="table-data">Task description 1</td>
    <td class="table-data">Task description 2</td>
    <td class="table-data">Task description 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td id="taskName1"></td>
    <td id="taskName2"></td>
    <td id="taskName3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please don't post answers with only code, especially when there's this much of it. These answers aren't very useful because it doesn't tell the reader how you solved the problem, it just gives them a bunch of code to sift through. This answer is only useful to the OP because it only applies to their situation, however it may not even be useful to them in the sense that it's not teaching them anything beyond how to copy and paste your code. A good description of how and why this solves the problem provided will make it much easier applied to other slightly different situations.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, element `id`s should be unique. You have three `td`s with the same ID, which is bad to begin with.

If you want to add an input field to each `td` in turn (that is, if you click Add button twice, it adds the input to the first `td` and then second `td`), you need two things:

- Unique identifier for each `td`
- Global index that keeps track of which is the "current" `td` to add the input to.

Here's the solution:

```js
let currentIndex = 0;

function addTask() {
  let inputTask = document.getElementById('inputTask');
  console.log(inputTask.value);

  let ul = document.getElementById(`taskName-${currentIndex}`);
  ul.innerHTML += `<p class="table-data">${inputTask.value}</p>`;
  inputTask.value = '';
  
  currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % 3;
}
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputTask" placeholder="Enter your your task">
<button onclick="addTask()">Add</button>

<main>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-data">Task description 1</td>
      <td class="table-data">Task description 2</td>
      <td class="table-data">Task description 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="taskName-0"></td>
      <td id="taskName-1"></td>
      <td id="taskName-2"></td>
    </tr>
</main>
```